# Cannot deploy an app with git to EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, amazon-ec2, capistrano, public-key

I have set up amazon EC2 instance (working) and Github repo (working well).
When I try to deploy the app to EC2 with using Github repo, I get this error:

```
 ** [IP] Permission denied (publickey).
 ** [IP] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 **
 ** Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 ** and the repository exists.
```

What am I missing? I can deploy an app to EC with using **copy**, but not with using github.

What do I need to set up the publickey?

**EDIT: SETUP**

```
set :application, "project_name"
set :user, 'username'
set :password, "password"

set :domain, "IP.amazonaws.com"
set :deploy_to, "/path_to_directory"
set :use_sudo, false

role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true 

set :assets_role, [:app]

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :repository, "git@github.com:user/repo.git"
set :scm, "git"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set up your SSH keys between EC2 and Github correctly based on the error message, but given the information you've provided, it's not possible to provide suggestions.

Question - have you set up a deploy key on the EC2 server?  I'm assuming that you are trying to deploy from the EC2 server and not your local machine using SSH Agent Forwarding.  Can you do a git pull from the EC2 server to the github account?  Can you ssh to git@github.com (e.g. "ssh -T git@github.com")?

The links below can help you setup a deploy key or figure out another way to manage deployment.

https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano

https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys

Comment: Hi William, thank you for your answer. Check out, please, the updated OP, I added information about deployment

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to debug access privileges when beginning to use Capistrano is to try accessing your server without it.